# Langton's Ant Constantly Moving Diagonally

Tags: java, grid, processing, cell, simulation

I have been working on a processing script to simulate Langton's Ant, however I am encountering an issue where it will only move diagonally. I have been trying to fix it for a while now, but I couldn't figure out what was causing the issue. I suspect it may have to do with the turn() function.

Here is the code:

```
int[][] grid;
int row;
int col;
int dir = 0;
final int DIR_UP = 0;
final int DIR_RIGHT = 1;
final int DIR_DOWN = 2;
final int DIR_LEFT = 3;

void setup()
{
  size(500, 500);
  background(255);

  grid = new int[width][height];
  col = width / 2;
  row = height / 2;
}

void draw()
{
  go();
}

void go()
{
  int pix = col + row * width;
  int state = grid[row][col];

  loadPixels();

  if(state == 0)
  {
    turn(1);
    grid[row][col] = 1;

    pixels[pix] = color(255);
  }
  else
  {
    turn(-1);
    grid[row][col] = 0;

    pixels[pix] = color(0);
  }

  updatePixels();

  move();
}

void turn(int rotation)
{
  dir += rotation;

  if(dir < 0)
  {
    dir = 3;
  }
  else if(dir > 3)
  {
    dir = 0;
  }

  // Does not work, can return negative values
  //dir = (dir + rotation) % 4;
}

void move()
{  
  switch(dir)
  {
    case DIR_UP:
      row--;
    case DIR_RIGHT:
      col++;
    case DIR_LEFT:
      col--;
    case DIR_DOWN:
      row++;    
  }

  if(col < 0)
    col = width - 1;
  else if(col >= width)
    col = 0;

  if(row < 0)
    row = height - 1;
  else if(row >= height)
    row = 0;
}
```

Comment: Please do not add the solution to your question. If you found a solution that worked best for you, then you can accept it below or answer your own question. This site encourages multiple solutions from other users, as the one that worked best for you may not work the best for someone else.  Your question has been rolled back to its previous state. For more information, please visit the [help].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please get into the habit of [debugging your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging).

Particularly, step through your `switch` statement:

```
  switch(dir)
  {
    case DIR_UP:
      row--;
    case DIR_RIGHT:
      col++;
    case DIR_LEFT:
      col--;
    case DIR_DOWN:
      row++;    
  }
```

What happens when `dir` is `DIR_UP`? What happens when `dir` if `DIR_RIGHT`? Put together a simple sketch that tests just this part out, using hard-coded values for `dir`.

```
final int DIR_UP = 0;
final int DIR_RIGHT = 1;
final int DIR_DOWN = 2;
final int DIR_LEFT = 3;
int dir = DIR_UP;
switch(dir)
{
  case DIR_UP:
    println("up");
  case DIR_RIGHT:
    println("right");
  case DIR_LEFT:
    println("left");
  case DIR_DOWN:
    println("down");
}
```

You'll find that when `dir` is `DIR_UP`, the code actually executes all of the other directions as well. That's because `case` statements **fall through** and continue executing. A `case` statement is like a "start here" statement. If you want to avoid executing the rest of the cases, you can use the `break` keyword to break out of the `switch` statement:

```
final int DIR_UP = 0;
final int DIR_RIGHT = 1;
final int DIR_DOWN = 2;
final int DIR_LEFT = 3;
int dir = DIR_UP;
switch(dir)
{
case DIR_UP:
  println("up");
  break;
case DIR_RIGHT:
  println("right");
  break;
case DIR_LEFT:
  println("left");
  break;
case DIR_DOWN:
  println("down");
  break;
}
```

Please get into the habit of working in small isolated example programs like this, and please [debug your code](http://happycoding.io/tutorials/processing/debugging) to understand exactly what's going on in the future.

Comment: I apologize; I definitely should have tried isolating that portion of the code. That was the culprit, and it is now solved. Thank you for the help!